# Why does DeepL not translate single words correctly? Russian-> Polish / Polish-> Russian

Tags: deepl

Why does DeepL not translate single words correctly?

Example:

Wrong:

**przekrzywić
наклон

przekrzywić się
наклон**

Correct:

**przekrzywić
перекосить

przekrzywić się
перекоситься**

This is a small example, but I checked many thousands of words and they are all incorrect.
I tried to contact support but it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

1. DeepL is not a dictionary, it's a machine translation engine. The less common a language combination is, the less accurate the engine will be because less training data is available for this language combination. The best systems will be from/into English; as soon as the translation is between rare languages like PL and RU, the quality will decrease dramatically.
2. Neural machine translation works on a context basis, meaning every word is defined by the words surrounding it. The less context, the less accurate the translation.